# Cant access magento category page

Tags: magento-1.9

Can access magento category page

Error log below

```
Source model "megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno" not found for attribute "sw_cat_hide_menu_item"

Trace:
#0 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like module disabled so that source model does not work

megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno

so either you need to enable module or you need to go to db and find table eav_attribute and remove attribute sw_cat_hide_menu_item

Comment: how do i enable it?

Comment: there are no values in database :/

Comment: go to db and run below query : select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='sw_cat_hide_menu_item'

Comment: done but now I am getting error for this
Source model "megamenu/category_attribute_source_type_style" not found for attribute "sw_cat_block_type"

Comment: go to db and run below query : select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='sw_cat_block_type'  and remove it

Comment: should I remove all sw attribute

Comment: if your module disable then you can remove it.you can find module app/etc/modules/ where you can check module exist with sm name

Comment: is that solved?

Comment: there are so many entries agianst sw
SELECT * FROM `mg_eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code like 'sw_%'

Comment: sw_cat_block_type
sw_cat_static_width
sw_cat_block_columns
sw_cat_block_top
sw_cat_left_block_width
sw_cat_block_left
sw_cat_right_block_width
sw_cat_block_right
sw_cat_block_bottom
sw_cat_label
sw_cat_float_type
sw_icon_image
sw_font_icon
sw_ocat_hide_this_item
sw_ocat_category_icon_image
sw_ocat_category_font_icon
sw_ocat_category_hoverbgcolor
sw_ocat_additional_content
sw_product_staticblock_tab_1
sw_product_staticblock_tab_2
sw_product_staticblock_tab_3
sw_product_staticblock_tab_4
sw_product_staticblock_tab_5
sw_product_attribute_tab_1

Comment: I dont know why all of a sudden Iam getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Find "`sw_cat_hide_menu_item`" into database "`eav_attribute`" table and delete

Delete cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

sw is smartwave vendor. **IF AND ONLY IF** you have permanently removed files related to smartwave theme of your magento install run this command in mysql:

```
DELETE from eav_attribute where attribute_code LIKE 'sw_%';
```

the theme was coded very poorly and breaks site if you try to uninstall this theme and its extensions that came with it. This command fixed any magento errors I had related to removal of smartwave porto theme for magento 1.9